# I possess two scripts. How can I execute both concurrently using Python's multithreading capabilities?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I currently have two scripts. The first script is already operational on my server, utilizing 32 parallel threads. However, my server has a total of 64 threads available. Now, I have a second script and I'm wondering if it's feasible to employ the remaining 32 threads without disrupting the threads already in use by the first script.

this is my first script,

```
def main():
    cpu_count = 32
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count) as executor:  # Use the number of CPU cores as max_workers
        futures = [executor.submit(process_file, filename) for filename in file_list]
    
        # Wait for all tasks to complete
        for future in futures:
            future.result()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the server's OS is windows.

Comment: Your server has thousands of threads running at any point in time.  Your additional 32 aren't going to upset it in any way.

Comment: There may be a naming issue here - I would typically say that there are 64 cores on the machine and that the python pool is running 32 processes. I'd reserve threads for execution threads within a process. There can be a large number of processes running, potentially waiting on I/O or competing for slices on the core.

Comment: You could just start the other script on its own. Do you want this script to start the other one? When this script ends, would you like it to wait for the other script to complete (that's easier!).

Comment: But generally, its feasible to run the other script to use the other cores. You've got plenty of CPUs available. But memory is another constraint. If you don't have enough memory, these processes may cause swapping, killing performance. There is a potential for I/O performance. If both are network intensive, they may overcommit there. Take a look at perfmon or other performance tools to decide how far you can push the server.

Comment: @thdelaney My initial script is expected to run for an extensive duration due to its need to process over 1TB of data. Given this lengthy timeframe, I can't afford to wait until its completion. Additionally, I must initiate the second script independently, which also requires parallel execution.

Comment: Being theoretically feasible does not guarantee that it can be done in practice. What you need to do is find a way to monitor if the first script is being disrupted while the second script is running.